# Check for multiple file in a list using Tcl

Tags: tcl

I have a directory (with sub directories) that contains *.ini files. I can read the files and have created a list.

I'm wondering/struggling to work out how to check for existence/count multiple files of same name in the list.

I wondered if someone could make suggestions

Thanks in advance.

i.e. check to see if Myfile.ini occurs more than once.

```
set fcheck "Myfile.ini"
for {set a 0} {$a < [llength $flist]} {incr a} {

set count [lsearch -glob $flist $fcheck ]

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easy way to find how many times each item occurs in a list is to use an associative array (the array `freq` needs to be unset or empty).

```
foreach item $list {
    incr freq($item)
}
```

The `parray` command can be used to print the resulting frequency table: `parray freq`.

If you just want to see which elements occur more than once:

```
foreach {key val} [array get freq] {
    if {$val > 1} {
        puts "$key: $val"
    }
}
```

To see how often the element "foo" occurs:

```
puts $freq(foo)
```

Documentation:
[> (operator)](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/expr.htm),
[array](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/array.htm),
[foreach](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/foreach.htm),
[if](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/if.htm),
[incr](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/incr.htm),
[parray](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/library.htm),
[puts](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/puts.htm)

Comment: Hi Peter, this works well and looks for multiple instances for any file. How would I look for multiple instance of a specific file? e.g. check to see if Myfile.ini occurs more than once.

Comment: @Anju: look at the last example. You would write something like `if {$freq(Myfile.ini) > 1} ...`